# email forwarding services - on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'd like to ask for advice regarding how to choose or evaluate email forwarding services (as opposed to recommendations of specific ones) - what criteria or considerations I should apply. This is for a (very) small business.

Would this be on-topic on SF?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, questions to learn about what criteria to apply when searching for a service are on-topic. You should make it extra clear that you are not looking for specific recommendations.